# Rewriting certain URL's using Regex in Google Analytics Filters

Tags: regex, filter, google-analytics, universal-analytics

How do I rewrite

```
/product-category-xyz/prefix-product-name-and-model
```

into

```
/prefix/product-category-xyz/product-name-and-model
```

for easier reporting in Content Drilldown report?

[image: Advanced filter function in GA]

Answer (score 2):

one possible solution..

**Regex:**

```
(.*\/)(.*?)-(.*)
```

**Substitution:**
/\2\1\3

**Demo:**
http://regex101.com/r/zD6iJ3/1

Comment: I will try this one, as I'm not sure if RegEx within GA allows the use of numbers in Substitution. I will verify that.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work as RegEx within GA does not allow the use of numbers corresponding with capture groups. [description](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en)

Comment: GA does allow for capture groups, but they are prefixed with $A or $B depending on if you're capturing from Field A or B. See nyuen's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this out:

```
Extract A: "Request URI"; ^(\/.*)(\/.*)-(.*)
Extract B: {leave blank}
Constructor: $A2$A1/$A3
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the regex on this one is wrong. The current RegExp would yield this result: `/prefix-product-name-and/product-category-xyz/model`. The only reason I comment is that this answer had me confused for a while.